# Laravel multiple insert in a table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a post and be able to add different categories, so I made this code

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request,[
    'title' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
    'name'=>'required'
  ]);

  $post = new \App\Post([
      'title' => $request->get('title'),
      'body' => $request->get('body')
    ]);
     $post->save();

     foreach ($request->name as $data) {
       $categories = new \App\Category();
       $categories->name = $request->get('name');
       //dd($categories);
      $post->categories()->save($categories);
     }
      return redirect()->route('create');
}
```

model Post

```
public function categories(){return $this->hasMany(\App\Category::class, 'post_id');}
```

model Category

```
public function something(){return $this->belongsTo(\App\Solicitud::class, 'post_id');}
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('store_data') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="title" class="col-md-4 control-label">title:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Cantidad" class="form-control"  value="{{ old('title') }}" />

                            @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('body') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="body" class="col-md-4 control-label">Body:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                          <input type="text" name="body" placeholder="Cantidad" class="form-control"  value="{{ old('body') }}" />

                            @if ($errors->has('body'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('body') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" class="form-control name_list"  value="{{ old('name') }}" /></td>
                            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"> + </button></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Create
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                          <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ URL::previous() }}">back</a> <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Scritps :

```
      <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var i=1;
   $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">-</button></td></tr>');
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
   });

});
</script>
```

but I get this error. when I submit the  form

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyect\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 681.
>
> "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyect\vendor\ ▶"

and if press submit with the input empty I get this error

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyect\resources\views\create.blade.php)

but if I edit the code, in this way it works but adds only one category.

```
$categories = new \App\Category();
       $categories->name = $request->get('name');
       //dd($categories);
      $post->categories()->save($categories);
```

I hope I have explained well and thanks :)

Comment: go ahead, just do this

Comment: you just have one input ! you need to add more of one input to your html form

Comment: <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" class="form-control name_list"  value="{{ old('name') }}" /> gonna add the scritps for the add button